# How to add an item to the secondary menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, routes

So far I've got the two standard menus in Drupal 7: the "main" and the "secondary" links, which are mapped to `Main menu` and `User menu` in the menu settings, respectively.

Now, I'd like to add a simple link to a contact form in the secondary menu, but I can't figure out how. Simply adding a link to `User menu` works fine when I'm logged in, but it doesn't show up for an anonymous user. It seems that the secondary menu doesn't show up at all for anonymous users, even if it is mapped to a custom menu (instead of `User menu`). Is there a way that one can configure the permissions for menus? If possible, I'd still like to have the logged-in menu links (like 'My account' and 'Log out'), as well as having some simple links that are always shown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was underestimating the system that Drupal uses to display menu items. **Links that go to locations that are unaccessible to the current user are not displayed.** So, for example, if an anonymous user cannot access a certain piece of content, then even the menu link to that content will be hidden.

I was using a contact form to test this with, but the problem was that the site-wide contact form is *hidden* by default. I just had to set the correct permissions, and voilà. Menu item shown.

Answer (score 3):

See www.domain.com/admin/structure/menu/settings

If you set both to "main menu", then the parent items will be in the main menu and child items will be in the second level menu. The menu system will respect the access system, so if a anonymous user does have access to content A. They will not see content A in the menu.

Hope it helps